# Clear cell changed metadata in OOO Calc

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I am trying to figure out how to clear the red highlighting around cells in Calc (OpenOffice 4).

Here is an example:
[image: Red highlight around cell]

It is not affecting my work but I would like to clear them as they are distracting. I have tried searching but all I can come up with is to clear everything in the cell which does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable [recording changes](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Recording_changes). Recording changes is a feature to keep some "metadata" about edits concerning your spreadsheet. It allows you to track some data about which changes were applied to the sheet, so a third person may review and acccept/reject the changes. When recording is enabled, every cell that was changed since is highlighted by a thin red border, and a popup informs about recent changed.

You can control recording of changed using Menu "`Edit`" -> "`Changes`". There, you will find also a feature to disable recording of changes: disable "`Record`". You will be asked for confirmation, but if you're not interested in the data recorded, you can safely confirm. "Data recorded" means the info in the popup box - date, time and content of edits regarding the specific cell, **not** the data in the cell itself.